# Capturing entire canvas as an image - Fabric JS

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

How do I capture my entire canvas as an image in Fabric JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need

```js
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('canvasContainer');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        fill:  "#FF0000",
        stroke: "black",
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        strokeWidth: 10, 
    });
   
   
    canvas.add(rect);
     
canvas.renderAll();
var convertToImage=function(){
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();  
  document.getElementById("ten").src=canvas.toDataURL('png'); 
}
convertToImage();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas  width="400" height="400" id="canvasContainer"></canvas>
<img id="ten" style="border:2px solid;"/>
```

Here as you can see i have not provided any src to the image. Instead the function convertToImage will set the source of the image.
Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy6j4078/2/)

**UPDATE:**

The above solution works only with `v1.x` from `v2.x` onwards the function `deactivateAll` is no longer available instead use `discardActiveObject` Check out this issue for more details [Github Issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4214)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore can you please update the answer with the working script.

Comment: @SundeepPidugu please check have updated the demo also the relevant change due to which it was failing

Comment: I tried doing that but it always show me `Cannot read property 'clearRect' of null` when i try to use the `toDataURL()` how do i fix that?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu can you create a fiddle.. not sure what issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() - [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

You can get a data-URL of the canvas with the following lines:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Then use the dataURL to display or save the image to a file and then display it.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on SO. Please add the relevant content directly to your answer.